# Convert exponential notation of number (e+) to 10^ in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I have a script, where I can convert gigs to megs to kilobytes to bytes to bits.

After that it uses the `.toExponential` function to turn it into scientific notation.

But I want it to change into an exponent, instead of it being `+e#` I want it to be `^#`, any way I can change it to print that way instead, if not, anyway I can alter the string to change `+e` to `^`?

Code:

```js
console.log('calculator');
const gigabytes = 192;
console.log(`gigabytes equals ${gigabytes}`);
var megabytes = gigabytes * 1000;
console.log(`megabytes = ${megabytes}`);
var kilabytes = megabytes * 1000;
console.log (`kilabytes = ${kilabytes}`);
bytes = kilabytes * 1000;
console.log(`bytes = ${bytes}`);
bites = bytes * 8;
console.log(`bites are equal to ${bites}`);
console.log (bites.toExponential());
```

Comment: string replace?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
const bytes = '1.536e+12'
console.log(convert(bytes))

const inputs = [
  '1.536e+12',
  '1.536e-12',
  '123',
  '-123',
  '123.456',
  '-123.456',
  '1e+1',
  '1e-1',
  '0e+0',
  '1e+0',
  '-1e+0'
]

function convert(value) {
  return value.replace(/e\+?/, ' x 10^')
}

inputs.forEach(i => console.log(convert(i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace `e+` with `^` using `replace`

```js
console.log('calculator');
const gigabytes = 192;
console.log(`gigabytes equals ${gigabytes}`);
var megabytes = gigabytes * 1000;
console.log(`megabytes = ${megabytes}`);
var kilabytes = megabytes * 1000;
console.log (`kilabytes = ${kilabytes}`);
bytes = kilabytes * 1000;
console.log(`bytes = ${bytes}`);
bites = bytes * 8;
console.log(`bites are equal to ${bites}`);
console.log (bites.toExponential().replace(/e\+/g, '^'));
```

Comment: But presumably the requested format would actually look like `1.536 x 10^12`.

Comment: nevermind I mistook what I was looking for, your right, I forgot about The more exact parts such as 1.536.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
console.log(bites.toExponential);
```

You may need to use

```
bites = bites.toExponential;
console.log(bites.replace(“e+”, “*10^”);
```

Hope this helped!